# How to inherit attributes of instance from PyQt5 code

Tags: python, oop, pyqt5, python-3.7

I am trying to create a GUI using PyQt5. I have an external script with functions, to change values on the screen. However I cannot access the attributes of the Qt object externally.

In my external script I have tried:

```
Main.MainWindow.label_55...
Main.ui.label_55...
```

And multiple other variations

*Main is the name of the PyQT5.py file

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: module 'Main' has no attribute 'MainWindow'
```

Comment: Please post an example showing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I suppose by "accessing externally" you mean "by importing". If you import a module with an "import protection" statement like

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

the code inside this block does not run. It only runs when you execute the module directly, not  via an import. That's why the other module does not see `MainWindow`.

If that's your main app window you should probably make imports the other way round. The main app imports other modules and calls them, eventually passing the main window or other objects as parameters.